# What is the recommended practice for detachable threads :pthread_detach or pthread_attr_setdetachstate?

Tags: pthreads

To create detachable Posix thread there is  two solutions :

1. pthread_attr_t ThreadAttr; pthread_attr_init(&ThreadAttr); pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&ThreadAttr, PTHREAD_CREATE_DETACHED); pthread_create(...); pthread_attr_destroy(&ThreadAttr)
2. pthread_detach(...)

   Whatis the Pro & Con of each solutions?

Answer (score 1):

The syntax for `pthread_detach` is simpler.  The approach based on thread attributes gives the implementation an opportunity to optimize the creation of the new thread because it does not have to support future calls of `pthread_detach` or `pthread_join` on the thread.

Furthermore, according to POSIX, setting the detachstate attribute to `PTHREAD_CREATE_DETACHED` is the only way to create a non-joinable thread, and `pthread_detach` does not turn a joinable thread into a non-joinable thread.  But [glibc gets this wrong](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=22337), so it might not matter to you.